# Pimcore pixlr api integration

Tags: pimcore, pixlr

Right now i am testing features of pimcore.

Really it has nice integration with pixlr but it is showing some problem on local machine.

Actually i have built a virtual host `pmc.com` with `port 81`. 
What happens when i click on `edit image` to edit an image pimcore generates url like 
[http://pmc.com/admin/assests/..](http://pmc.com/admin/assests).
Its does not add the `port 81` so i am unable to save & edit images on `localhost`.

Can any one help me to solve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a member of Pimcore's team:

> if you have a closed System Pixlr cannot load your image by the local url. (Example `http://localhost/admin/asset/get-image-thumbnail`)
>   a possibility could be realized by using dyndns.org so Pixlr can handle your picture

[Pixlr cannot load a local image](http://www.pimcore.org/board/viewtopic.php?t=967&p=3586)

In other words, you must have an accessible host in order to Pixlr can load your picture (pcm.com is a virtual host for your machine and is not visible from internet).

Hope this help.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your answer. Pimcore is more confusing about its features, did not found any place to contact its developer team about features, unable to post on forum, @Laleft can i have any contact details whom i can ask some questions about pimcore.

Comment: Hi, onkarjanwa. I don't have direct contact with Pimcore's team, but you must insist in forums. Pimcore is not easy. I spent months to understand how it works, and some things are not clear to me yet. Think that it implements two complex frameworks to run: ZF and ExtJS! and it was developed to have advance features wich requires advanced knowledge. Moreover, Pimcore's community is small and sometimes is not easy to get help. I think the core team works really hard to share their code and they don't have much time for the community. However, they quickly fix errors and add improvements to code.

Comment: By the way, Pimcore is a CMF (Content Management Framework) wich means that you have to build your own templates, layouts, snippets, etc. Pimcore offers a set of tools to build these things, but is not a CMS out-of-the-box. I strongly recommend yout to have patient and read all the documentation. Then, use the forums to ask specific questions. That worked for me. Luck!

Comment: thanks for your great response. I realy found that it has not CMS feature out-of-the-box.